# Javascript HTML5 Audio- Which function to reference in addEventListner for songs?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, addeventlistener

```
function media () {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class", "container");
    foo.appendChild(div);

    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    audio.setAttribute("controls", "controls");

    var source = document.createElement("source");
    source.setAttribute("src", "media/dimples.ogg");
    source.setAttribute("type", "audio/ogg");
    source.setAttribute("src", "media/dirty_feeling.ogg");
    source.setAttribute("type", "audio/ogg");
    source.setAttribute("src", "media/suzieq.ogg");
    source.setAttribute("type", "audio/ogg");
    source.setAttribute("src", "media/wear_my_ring.ogg");
    source.setAttribute("type", "audio/ogg");
    audio.appendChild(source);

    div.appendChild(audio);

    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.setAttribute("id", "playlist");

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", "#song1");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Dimples");
    a.appendChild(text);
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);

    li = document.createElement("li");
    a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", "#song2");
    text = document.createTextNode("Dirty Feeling");
    a.appendChild(text);
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);  

    li = document.createElement("li");
    a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", "#song3");
    text = document.createTextNode("Suzie Q");
    a.appendChild(text);
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);  

    li = document.createElement("li");
    a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", "#song4");
    text = document.createTextNode("Wear My Ring");
    a.appendChild(text);
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li); 

    div.appendChild(ul);

    foo.lastChild.scrollIntoView();
    musicColors();
}
```

This is my fist attempt to create a media player. It has to be in Javascript and I refuse to use jquery(no jquery suggestions please).

I got 2 questions, please:
1) All the song links blend together in one line. Why is this since each li is a child of ul?
2) I was going to create a  addEventListner for the song links, but I am not sure what function to reference that actually plays the song?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a global ul = display: inline I didn't see.

audio src need to be re-assigned for each new song. I did with using the javascript Audio object and reused the object for each song.